# C Design: Pass memory address or return

Tags: c

In some functions (such as *scanf variants) there is a argument that takes a memory space for the result. You could also write the code where it returns an address. What are the advantages, why design the function in such a weird way?

Example

```
void process_settings(char* data)
{
    .... // open file and put the contents in the data memory
    return;
}
```

vs

```
char* process_settings()
{
    char* data = malloc(some_size);
    .... // open file and load it into data memory
    return data;
}
```

Comment: What if you don't want to allocate every time you call the function?

Comment: Why wouldn't you? Shouldn't the function be compartmentalized and be responsible for it's own memory and malloc calls?

Comment: Not for memory that it hands back to the caller.

Comment: So should a function ever call malloc for memory it is returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefit is that you can reserve the return value of the function for error checking, status indicators, etc, and actually send back data using the output parameter. In fact, with this pattern, you can send back any amount of data along with the return value, which could be immensely useful. And, of course, with multiple calls to the function (for example, calling `scanf` in a loop to validate user input), you don't have to `malloc` every time.

One of the best examples of this pattern being used effectively is the function `strtol`, which converts a string to a `long`.

The function accepts a pointer to a character as one of its parameters. It's common to declare this `char` locally as `endptr` and pass in its address to the function. The function will return the converted number if it was able to, but if not, it'll return `0` to indicate failure *but also* set the character pointer passed in to the non-digit character it encountered that caused the failure.

You can then report that the conversion failed on that particular character.

This is better design than using global error indicators; consider multithreaded programs. It likely isn't reasonable to use global error indicators if you'll be calling functions that could fail in several threads.

You mention that a function should be responsible for its own memory. Well, `scanf` doesn't exist to *create* the memory to store the scanned value. It exists to scan a value from an input buffer. The responsibilities of that function are very clear and don't include allocating the space.

It's also not unreasonable to return a `malloc`'d pointer. The programmer should be prudent, though, and `free` the returned pointer when they're done using it.

Comment: But why would you just return an array. For example with atoi an int[] with int[0] being an error detail, and int[1] the value? I guess it's because I'm coming from python where arguments are stuff going in to the function and  return is for everything going out.

Comment: In C, you can't return an array, you need to return a pointer to an array which also requires a `malloc`. It's just another thing to `free`. :) Plus, in an `int[]` array, you can only store `int`s. What if the error code is an int, but I'm filling a string buffer? You can't smash two different types into an array. It may not be immediately intuitive, but this is a very efficient design.

Comment: I guess my issue is the intuitiveness.  Instead of  int[] it could be a struct. Ya it requires malloc but it seems you either get that or weird argument things. Return at least keeps the idea of arguments in -> return out. I don't know I'm trying to find a design resource that address this.

Comment: [Here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Function_Parameter_Ordering) is Google's C++ style guide discussing output parameters. Trust me, the more you work with C library functions, the more useful this notation becomes.

Comment: Yes and that i fine normal but using arguments as data output still seems odd. I'll read the Google style guide.

Comment: When you provide a callback, you're really just creating a way to "return" more items; your callback can accept arguments, and the original function will pass them. The concept here is no different, except it's done without callbacks and instead through mutating the parameters given. Why else would we be able to us the `const` keyword in function parameters?

Answer (score 3):

The decision of using one method instead of another depends on what you intend to do.

Example

If you want to modify an array inside a function an maintain the modification in the original array, you should use your first example.

If you are creating your own data structure, you have to deal with all the operations. And if you want to create a new struct you should allocate memory inside the function and return the pointer. The second example.

If you want to "return" two values from a function, like a vector and the length of the vector, and you don't want to create a struct for this, you could return the pointer of the vector and pass an int pointer as an argument of the function. That way you could modify the value of the int inside the function and you use it outside too.

```
char* return_vector_and_length(int* length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say that, for example, you wanted to store process settings in a specific place in memory.  With the first version, you can write this as, `process_settings(output_buffer + offset);`.  How would you have to do it in you only had the second version?  What would happen to performance if it were a really big array?  Or what if, let’s say, you’re writing a multithreaded application where having all the threads call `malloc()` all the time would make them fight over the heap and serialize the program, so you want to preallocate all your buffers?

Your intuition is correct in some cases, though: on modern OSes that can memory-map files, it does turn out to be more efficient to return a pointer to the file contents than the way the standard library was historically written, and this is how `glib` does it.  Sometimes allocating all your buffers on the heap helps avoid buffer overflows that smash the stack.

An important point is that, if you have the first version, you can trivially get the second one by calling `malloc` and then passing the buffer as the dest argument.  But, if you have only the second, you can’t implement the first without copying the whole array.